# Threepenny-GUI: Drag'n'Drop - Access DragData

Tags: haskell, drag-and-drop, threepenny-gui

I am currently struggling with getting access to the `DragData` of the dragged element when the `on UI.drop` is called. I have something like this:

```
tile <- UI.new
    # set UI.draggable True
    # set UI.dragData (show player)

field <- UI.new
    # set UI.droppable True

on UI.drop field $ \_ -> do
    -- How to receive the DragData here?
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance!

Greetings,
Moritz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it:

```
on UI.drop field $ \dragData -> do
    d <- read dragData
```

Maybe it helps someone else ;)